# Using OpenCV Java Bindings to read an image

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, javacv

I'm using the new [OpenCV Java bindings](http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html) to read an image and do some processing on the image. I'm trying to convert C code to Java using the Java bindings but can't seem to find the relevant methods:

C code:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread(argv[1]);
cv::Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
int erosion_size = 5;
cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_CROSS,
                                       cv::Size(2 * erosion_size + 1, 2 * erosion_size + 1),
                                       cv::Point(erosion_size, erosion_size) );
cv::erode(gray, gray, element);
```

I can't find:

- `imread`
- `cvtcolor`
- `getStructuringElement`
- `erode`

I looked around the api here: http://docs.opencv.org/java/

Unfortunately the [sample java code provided](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/java/ant/src/SimpleSample.java) doesn't even show how to read an image!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have correctly installed Opencv with support for Java desktop and included `opencv-2.4.4.jar` , your should import:

```
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
```

And your code will look like this:

```
Mat img = Highgui.imread(argv[1], Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
int erosion_size = 5;
Mat element  = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(
    Imgproc.MORPH_CROSS, new Size(2 * erosion_size + 1, 2 * erosion_size + 1), 
    new Point(erosion_size, erosion_size)
);
Imgproc.erode(img, img, element);
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but i configured open-cv and all, i try running your code andi get: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread_0(Ljava/lang/String;I)J
 at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread_0(Native Method)
 at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread(Highgui.java:306)
 at pack.ColoredObjectTrack.main(ColoredObjectTrack.java:41)"

Comment: You have not correctly referenced native library. Follow the [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html#introduction-to-java-development) with more attention.

Answer (score 26):

To read an image with OpenCV for Java:

#### OpenCV 2.x ([JavaDoc](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/highgui/Highgui.html#imread(java.lang.String)))

```
Mat img = Highgui.imread("path/to/img");
```

#### OpenCV 3.x ([JavaDoc](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/imgcodecs/Imgcodecs.html#imread-java.lang.String-))

```
Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread("path/to/img");
```

---

In both versions you can pass a second parameter specifying how to load the image:

- `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH`: returns 16-bit/32-bit image when the input has the corresponding depth, otherwise convert it to 8-bit.
- `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR`: always convert image to a color one.
- `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE`: always convert image to a grayscale one.

Example:

```
// OpenCV 2.x   
Mat img = Highgui.imread("path/to/img", Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
// OpenCV 3.x
Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread("path/to/img", Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

Comment: This is a cleaner answer.

Comment: Seems in the current OpenCV the constant is Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE

Answer (score 1):

for macOs you can use :

```
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;


Mat logo = Imgcodecs.imread("resources/images/gambar.jpg");
```

for me, I use opencv_java320.dll

Answer (score 0):

There is an important update to [answer by @David Miguel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40450651/9640177).

`Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE` is no longer available in opencv 4.x. You should rather use `Imgcodecs.imread("/resources/images/test.png", Imgcodecs.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` to load gray-scale image.